# creating thousands of urls through mod-rewrite

Tags: php, mysql, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm programming a website which has a lot of users stored in a mysql_database where each user has an ID and profilename (like **jim.button.1**) among other fields. I want an url (which get's the profile through e.g a mysql_select on the userID) that has this structure: **www.mysite.com/jim.button.1**

Now I know that I could do that with a mod_rewrite_rule, but with thousands of users I'll get a very large .htaccess file. I'm not by far an expert in mod rewrite by the way, but I understand how it works.

Is there a way to do this, say in one or two mod_rewrite_rules or is there another smart way to accomplish this?

All help is welcome.

Answer (score 2):

You could rewrite all URLs that don't map to an existing file, using:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
    RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
    RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

Then grab the actual URL via `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`. Here's an example:

```
$parts = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
$user = $parts['path'];
```

See https://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication/blob/master/public/.htaccess for an example.

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ users.php?user=$1 [QSA,L]
```

In your users.php you can get the user like this:

```
$user = $_GET['user'];
// do your stuff with the user
```

You have to fine tune this to get it integrated with the rest of your site, but you get the idea.

Comment: Your rewrite rule will match *every* request, so actual files (`.css`, `.js`, `.jpg`, etc) will not be served. Probably not what the OP wants.

Answer (score 1):

I would combine both Ross Smith's and JvdBerg's so you'd end up with something like:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
    RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ profile.php?user=$1 [NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

which would make it easier to process in your script rather than having to parse the entire URL.  The beginning 4 lines after turning on the `RewriteEngine` are needed so the rest of the site can continue to operate (checks directory, file, links) and if the url is one will use the first rule and not process any more.  And then the second rule is if it isn't one of the previous and redirects as a get to your 'profile.php' page.

Then in your 'profile.php' page, you can get your values as:

```
list($fname, $lname, $id) = explode('.', $_REQUEST['user']);
```

And go from there.

Comment: I also want to add that if you plan on adding more rules later, you should be as specific as possible with your `RewriteRule`'s now.  So changing `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ profile.php?user=$1 [NC,L]` to `RewriteRule ([a-zA-Z]+)\.([a-zA-Z]+)\.([0-9]+)$ profile.php?fname=$1&lname=$2&uid=$3 [NC,L]` and accessing them via `$_REQUEST['fname']`, `$_REQUEST['lname']`, and `$_REQUEST['uid']` in your script.  It will also ensure that the format is what you expect, and restrict the URI to have character sets that you are expecting for your PHP.

Comment: At last I have time to implement this and your answer is very uselfull! Thank you.

Comment: Why the downvote?  If you're going to downvote something, at least leave a comment as to why.